# Input Box Value system

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

```
    Private Sub btnConfirmInfantry_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirmInfantry.Click
    Dim input = InputBox("How many do you want to attack with?", "Choose how many Infantry:")
    Dim infantry As Integer
    If (input > frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error: The inputted number has to be <= current number of infantry.")
    Else

        If Integer.TryParse(input, infantry) Then
            Dim hpai = Integer.Parse(frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", hpai - infantry * 2)

            Dim numPlayer = frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text    'Integer.Parse(frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text)
            frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text = (numPlayer - input).ToString("N0")

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I am attempting to get the If (input > frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text) Then Skip the rest of the line of code.
But, the issue is that the lblInfantry numbers are in the millions and it is only reading the first number which is 2. So if I input 3, the error msgbox will occur. I have tried the Globilization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands by putting it after the frm.... but that did not work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Note: I want to put a input value of like 30 in and if the lblInfantry is like 100,000 then the msgbox will NOT occur and the code will read after the Else.

Update:

```
    Private Sub btnConfirmInfantry_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirmInfantry.Click
           Dim input = InputBox("How many do you want to attack with?", "Choose how many Infantry:")
    Dim infantry As Integer

    Dim intInfanty As Integer = 0
    Dim intInput As Integer = 0
    Dim txt As String = frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text, intInfantry

    If Integer.TryParse(input, intInput) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(txt, intInfantry) AndAlso (intInput > intInfantry) Then
        If (IsNumeric(input) AndAlso IsNumeric(frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text) AndAlso CInt(input) > CInt(frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("The value can not be a letter.")
        Else

            If Integer.TryParse(input, infantry) Then
                Dim hpai = Integer.Parse(frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                frmMainGame.lblHPAI.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", hpai - infantry * 2)

                Dim numPlayer = frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text    'Integer.Parse(frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text)
                frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text = (numPlayer - input).ToString("N0")

            End If
        End If
    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Error: The inputted number has to be <= current number of infantry.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: InputBox results and Text properties are strings.  You have to TryParse them into numbers before evaluating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your input values to integers. Using a comparative operator like `>` on strings will do the comparison *alphabetically*, so for example, `"20000" < "3"` returns `true` - alphabetically, `20000` comes first.

```
Dim intInfanty as int = 0;
Dim intInput as int = 0;
Dim txt as String = frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text, intInfantry;

If Int.TryParse(input, intInput) AndAlso Int.TryParse(txt, intInfantry) Then
    If (intInput > intInfantry)  Then
        'Input > InfantryNumberPlayer
    Else
        'Input <= InfantryNumberPlayer
    End If
Else
    'Skipped the > comparison because one of them wasn't a number
    '"Please make sure you entered a valid number"
End If
```

---

If you want to combine the `If` statements so that non-numeric values fall into the same `else` as the `>` comparison, you can do this:

```
Dim intInfanty as int = 0;
Dim intInput as int = 0;
Dim txt as String = frmMainGame.lblInfantryNumberPlayer.Text, intInfantry;

If Int.TryParse(input, intInput) AndAlso Int.TryParse(txt, intInfantry) AndAlso (intInput > intInfantry) Then
    'Input > InfantryNumberPlayer
Else
    'Anything else happened
    '(Input was <= InfantryNumberPlayer, OR one wasn't a number)
End If
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much! I will keep this in mind next time.

Comment: No problem. The script I've written above is admittedly quick and dirty - If the numbers cannot be converted to integers, *the script will throw an error*. I will write a more proper solution. **EDIT:** I've added a failsafe. If either of the values aren't numeric, the code will fall into the `else` case.

Comment: @CaptainCaboose One last edit... This is the safest method!

Comment: How would I then get if not numerical then it show the error message? Would I put IsNot before the 2nd AndAlso statement?

Comment: So if the values aren't numeric, you want it to fall into the same `else` as the `>` comparison? Added to answer.

Comment: So do I want that added with the If or? I am confused haha. (I am a VB noob as well)

Comment: Take a look at the differences in the comments in my examples above. The first example lets you separate the case "what if one of the values isn't a number?", whereas the second says "If one of the values isn't a number, just treat it as if txtInfantry wasn't less than the input"

Comment: Alright, I got what you said. Is this an issue though?
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning BC42030 Variable 'intInfantry' is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: Either method is valid. It's up to you to choose what you want to do if they enter something that isn't a number.

Comment: Ok, so please tell me, everything correct? Look at the edit in main above.

Comment: Just curious because I inputted a letter and no msgbox appeared. Just skipped the code.

Comment: No. Your code is not correct. Where you have `the value cannot be a letter` is where the code should go if they enter a value *correctly*.

Comment: Oh, I think I just understood what you wrote!

Comment: Alright, I got the letter error to work but it replaces the Number is too big error message box.

Comment: Alright, here is the new issue. That code, the way I wrote it from instructions, the number can not be inputted. What have I done wrong? The updated code is above too.

Comment: I got it actually. Thank you for the help!